# How to attach data to DOM elements for jQuery consumption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items, all having an id and a value. I print this list in a php view script using divs, like this:

```
<div class="myList">
    <div class="listItem item3 value4">item label</div>
    <div class="listItem item5 value7">item label</div>
    ...
</div>
```

The idea is to include some jQuery to attach some edit functionality to the list items. To manipulate each item I need the item ID and value ID in jQuery, which I now determine by looking for the class patterns itemID and valueID and extracting the ID part (which is of course a number for each item. These IDs I then use to do an ajax call to update the right item from the list (giving it a new value ID the user can pick)

My question: the way I'm doing this works, but doesn't seem too elegant to me. The jQuery .data method doesn't seem to help here, the data needs to be printed by a php view script before jQuery comes into play so the data needs to be present in the html structure and read by jQuery afterwards. I thought of custom html attributes

```
<div class="listItem" itemID="4" valueID="7">labeltext</div>
```

But is this good practice? Is there a better way to 'feed' data to jQuery? How is this usually done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML5 [`data` attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```
<div class="listItem" data-item-id="4" data-value-id="7">labeltext</div>
```

You'll have the benefit of using jQuery's [`.data()` syntax](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$('.listItem').eq(0).data('item-id'); // Returns: 4
```

Comment: This sounds great, but is it gonna work on older browsers (say IE7)?

Comment: When you use jQuery's .data() after typing in the data attributes in html, the names become camel-cased.  So in the above example, the jQuery call should be $('.listItem').eq(0).data('itemId');

Comment: To bypass the weird naming mishaps, you can use jQuery to attach the data to begin with:  `$('.listItem').data('itemId', 4);` Then you can retrieve it with the same key: `$('.listItem').data('itemId');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data attribute :

```
<div class="listItem"
     data-id="4"
     data-valueId="7">
       labelText
</div>
```

and recover them in JS using : 
(when your selector is on a listItem class)

```
...
var $this = $(this); //just an habit ;)
var id = $this.data('id');
var valueId = $this.data('valueId');
...
```